# SDL Surface Gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS In Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sdl, exc-bad-access

Lately I've been trying to teach myself SDL in C++ from the tutorials of LazyFoo (lazyfoo.net). After studying his first ten tutorials or so and playing around with them a little I decided to have a go creating a tile set engine, trying to modify his [tutorial 39](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/39_tiling/index.php) to solely use a tileset (the original tutorial also includes a moving dot, collision detection and a viewport).

However, I quickly ended up with Xcode giving me an error in Thread 1, defined as *EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)*. Thinking it was just a sloppy coding mistake, I tried to build and run the files [LazyFoo had linked to](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/39_tiling/index.php), but these gave similar errors.

The piece of code that gave the problem was the LTexture::loadFromFile function, which took one argument std::string path. The function is meant to load a surface from a file and then return it as a texture. The source code reads:

```
bool LTexture::loadFromFile( std::string path )
{
    //Get rid of preexisting texture
    free();

    //The final texture
    SDL_Texture* newTexture = NULL;

    //Load image at specified path
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load( path.c_str() );
   if( loadedSurface == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Unable to load image %s! SDL_image Error: %s\n", path.c_str(),     IMG_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        //Color key image
        SDL_SetColorKey( loadedSurface, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB( loadedSurface->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

        //Create texture from surface pixels
        newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( gRenderer, loadedSurface );
        if( newTexture == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Unable to create texture from %s! SDL Error: %s\n", path.c_str(), SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
            //Get image dimensions
            mWidth = loadedSurface->w;
            mHeight = loadedSurface->h;
        }

        //Get rid of old loaded surface
        SDL_FreeSurface( loadedSurface );
    }

    //Return success
    mTexture = newTexture;
    return mTexture != NULL;
}
```

The line that gives the error is

```
SDL_SetColorKey( loadedSurface, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB( loadedSurface->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );
```

Once again, the error reads

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).

Should this line be deleted, this causes another error in the  subsequent line

```
newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( gRenderer, loadedSurface );
```

With a different code:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x100000071)

I've been googling for a solution and got a lot of hits on the GPFLT (which is supposed to mean General Protection Fault) but none of the solutions seem applicable to my problem. Does anybody see a problem in my code, or has anybody experienced alike problems in the past, so that this error can be resolved?

Thanks in advance,

Matthijs

Once again, I use SDL2 and SDL2-Image, downloaded with Homebrew as Dylibs. In the past, they have always worked. I program in C++ on a recent iMac with plenty of RAM, an i7 processor and the most recent version of OSX. My IDE is Xcode 6.1.1

Comment: Could you try just drawing the image from the surface without making it in to a texture or doing any other manipulation on it just to see if it loading correctly. It's possible that it is loading and getting a memory address but has other issues with it. Also try with another image.

Comment: I've already tried two different images. Tonight I'll also try to draw the surface itself. But that's still just a workaround, and not a solution. Should I later want to manipulate my textures, I'd have come no further. Nevertheless, thanks for the quick reply!